# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path when Deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Hi I'm trying to deserialize a json from a http response, but i always get this Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path error. What can I do to fix this?

This is my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        ///client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://admin.cssholdings.com/api/v3/AuthenticateLivePOSAdmin/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIApplicationID", _clientId);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIApplicationKey", _clientSecret);

        var PostData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        PostData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("strAdminUsername", adminusername));
        PostData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("strAdminPassword", password));
        PostData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("strAdminSecurityCode", securitycode));

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(PostData);
        string res = "";


        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("https://admin.cssholdings.com/api/v3/AuthenticateLivePOSAdminLogin/", content).Result;






        List<BO.AuthenticatedUser> authuser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BO.AuthenticatedUser>>(response.Content.ToString());
```

Then here's the json object that I saw on fiddler:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to handle JSON? JSON.NET? It would be helpful if you call that out and if you add it to the tags. Also - did you paste the whole JSON as it was in Fiddler? From the image, it seems like you are missing a closing bracket ']'. Also -it would be great if you could paste it as text rather than image.

Comment: Yes json.net, i checked it on jsonlint.com the json was valid

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem too. The problem, in my opinion, is the usage of ToString() methon on json object which returns the string that is in an incorrect format for the DeserializeObject method.
You can try using this approach(didn't work for me):

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken token = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
string templateMsgText = (string)token.SelectToken("yourKey");
```

Instead what I did was that I directly accepted the json string in my custom class and accessed its values via get;set.

Here's how I did it:

My server-side method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string onSubmit(TemplateDataText jsonString)
{ 
  return jsonString.templateMsgText;
}
```

This is my custom class designed to get the data:

```
public class TemplateDataText{
    public TemplateDataText(){}

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string templateMsgText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("optionSelected")]
    public string radioSelected { get; set; }

}
```

And here's my json coming via ajax POST request:

```
{"jsonString":{"text":"THIS IS THE TEXT THAT USER ENTERED","optionSelected":"2"}}
```

Using these settings I was able to get the "text" value in my server side method and was able to use it for further processing.